# Java Not Greater than Or Equal to Operator for Char Type

Tags: java, while-loop, char, operators, ascii

So I'm trying to write this in a short way:

```
char letter;
while ( letter!='A' && letter!='B' && letter!= 'C... letter!= 'a' 
                                                     && letter !='b' && letter!=c)
```

Basically if the user does not input a letter between A and C, a while loop will run until A,B,C,a,b,c is inputted.

It should be in the form of

`while(letter<'a' && letter > 'c')`

but it didn't work apparently because if I inputted F, is it greater than 'C', but it is less than 'c', since char uses ACSII.

Comment: can you show your code ?

Comment: Simple -- change the letter entered to either lower case or upper case and then check.

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to do this check.

```
char letter;
while (!(letter >= 'A' && letter <= 'C') && !(letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'c'))
```

Or you can use `Character.toUpperCase` or `toLowerCase` on the letter first, to remove half of the conditions.

Or, if the range of letters is small or non-contiguous, you could do:

```
char letter;
while ("ABCabc".indexOf(letter) == -1)
```

There are more ways of course.

Comment: the second way certainly looks more concise

Comment: More concise, yes. But I'd still prefer the first version. To me, the intent is much clearer in that one. Especially the way it is parenthesized and the use of the not-operator make it quite fluent to read in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Set letter to lower case and then check:

```
letter = Character.toLowerCase(letter);
while (letter < 'a' && letter > 'c') {
    // ...        
}
```

This way, even if the user enters an upper case letter, the check will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need two conditions and a bit of de Morgan:

```
while(!((letter >= 'A' && letter <= 'C') || (letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'c')))
```

Answer (score 0):

or good old regex

```
    char input = 'B';

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("a|b|c", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher m = p.matcher("" + input);
    if (m.find())
    {
        System.out.println("found");
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can check with ASCII code of characters such as 65 for 'A' and 97 for 'a'. So you could do if (letter > 65) to check if letter greater than 'A'. Hope this helps.
Updates :
For checking if letter is only either of A,B,C,a,b,c, use this check : if (letter >= 65 && letter <= 67) || (letter >= 97 && letter <= 99) .
Please mark as answer if this helps.

Comment: For checking if letter is only either of A,B,C,a,b,c, use this check : if (letter >= 65 && letter <= 67) || (letter >= 97 && letter <= 99)

Comment: I think what the downvoters are reacting to is that `'A'` is much more understandable in the problem domain than 65.